# Create text to on an HTML template after Window.onKeyDown

Tags: javascript, html

**update 0**

got this error message: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

**update 0**

**update 1 newest Source**

```
<html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
      <title>Reservations</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <center><h1>Reservations</h1></center>
    <div class="wrapper">

<p> You can start over at the beginning <a href="/">here.</a> </p>
<big>Reserve some courts online  </big> <br />
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    $( document ).keypress(function() {
    $("#timeStamp span").text("Timestamp is no-longer correct");
});
</script>
<form action="" method="post" >
       <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="Rogers"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="weekday" value="Tuesday"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="nowweekday" value="1"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="month" value="September"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="nowmonth" value="9"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="day" value="18"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="year" value="2012"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="startTime" value="[15, 0]"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="endTime" value="[20L, 0L]"></input>

       <input type="hidden" name="court" value="court1"></input>

       <input type="hidden" name="court" value="court2"></input>

       <h1>Tuesday, September 18, 2012 at Rogers Neighborhood Club</h1> 
   <div class="timeStamp" ><h1 id="timeStamp">15:07:24.657430<span></span></h1></div> <br />
```

**update 1 newest Source**

I have a timestamp on a page that is created on page load.

I want to alter the adjoining text label of the time stamp to indicate that the timestamp is no longer correct when there is a `keyDown` anywhere in the `window`.

Can that be done easily with javascript?

```
<html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
      <title>Reservations</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <center><h1>Reservations</h1></center>
    <div class="wrapper">

<p> You can start over at the beginning <a href="/">here.</a> </p>
<big>Reserve some courts online  </big> <br />
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    $("*").keypress(function() {
    $("#timeStamp").text("Modified");
    });
</script>

<form action="" method="post" >
       <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="Rogers"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="weekday" value="Tuesday"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="nowweekday" value="1"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="month" value="September"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="nowmonth" value="9"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="day" value="18"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="year" value="2012"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="startTime" value="[14, 30]"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="endTime" value="[20L, 0L]"></input>

       <input type="hidden" name="court" value="court1"></input>

       <input type="hidden" name="court" value="court2"></input>

       <h1>Tuesday, September 18, 2012 at Rogers Neighborhood Club</h1> 
   <div class="timeStamp" id="timeStamp"><h1>text14:49:30.274646</h1></div> <br />
```

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: So you want to listen to `keyDown` on any element in the document? What javascript libraries do you currently use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, like so:

Assuming you're using jQuery and have the timestamp HTML like this:

```
<p id="timeStamp">2012-09-18 20:08 <span></span></p>
<!-- the span is where the message will be inserted -->
```

...and the jQuery code itself:

```
$( document ).keypress(function() {
    $("#timeStamp span").text("Timestamp is no-longer correct");
});
```

Comment: You can attach the keydown event on the body, will probably be faster

Comment: I added the following code. `<script type="test/javascript" language="JavaScript"
    $("*").keypress(function() {
    $("#timeStamp").text("Modified");
    });
</script>`  and `<div> id ="timeStamp" class="timeStamp"><h1>{{ tod }}</h1></div>` within the <body></body>, but the web page stops printing out in the browser just before the `<script>`.  The {{...}} is because I am using jinja2.

Comment: Please post the relevant generated markup (not the source) to your original question.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know how to do that. I just learned of Chrome's developer's console for html. If what you need is somewhere in there, please describe where because All I see in the default window is minimal. Also, note there was a typo in my previous comment: `<div>` should have been `<div` . But changing that does not change the result. Only removing the <script> gives me the original content back, including `tod`.

Comment: in Chrome, get to the page's source, then copy and paste it into your original question by clicking the Edit button.

Comment: No, there was another typo. The `>` was missing at the end of the `<script ...>`. When I fixed that I got my full page in the browser, but there is no effect of key pressing, still.

Comment: Is anything written to the Javascript Console window in your browser? Also, try changing your script from `$("*")` to `$( document )`.

Comment: Did you see the error message I posted to the question? Does that mean I have to make the whole <body> some sort of <div>? Please give details if so.

Answer (score 0):

Change your body element like this : `<body onload="document.body.focus()" onkeyup="key()">`... It will execute the key function everytime a key is pressed. Do everything you want there..

Comment: no no no, inline javascript is not useful here... there are so many ways that can be overridden. Only resort to inline javascript when absolutely required.

Comment: I am using a jinja2 feature where there is a base.html containing a wrapper `  <body>
      <center><h1>Reservations</h1></center>
    <div class="wrapper">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
    </div>
  </body>`
 that extends all my other pages, so the <body> tag is not in this particular page.